# WiFi ESP8266 ESP-07 adapter role

Tags: relay, esp8266, cp2102

I'm confused about the role of the  [image: ESP-07 adapter]

Let's assume that I want to use it along with a [image: relay] and I want to flash it with  [image: CP2102].

The adapter should be used with both CP2102 and the relay or just with the relay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESP8266 adapter can be programmed using CP2102.

You can program your ESP8266 GPIO pin to trigger the relay.

Once the circuit will be fully functional, you can remove CP2102 module from the circuit. It is used only for programming.

Comment: I know that the CP2102 is removed after programming, but my question is about the ESP-07 adapter

Comment: Taking a close look at the adapter, I realized that few resistors are soldered with GPIO line. These resistors are important for proper booting of ESP micro-controller. If you don't wanted to use the breakout board, then look for adapter schematic and externally solder resistor to proper pins. If it seems a painful process, then look here... https://internetofhomethings.com/homethings/?p=605

Comment: Do I need the board after I remove the CP 2102?

Comment: No need to use adapter at all if you can directly solder needed resistors as per schematic. As already mentioned about booting operation, it'll be useful every time the board powered up.